# Removing directory name from url

Tags: git, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So here is my situation. I'm developing a website an my local machine, which runs on windows. The structure of my directory is similar to the plan below.

**Local machine**

```
local_project/
    |-- directory1
    |-- directory2
    |-- file1.txt
```

This project is saved on github, within a directory with a different name (here, i used 'github_project' as an example):

**On github**

```
github_project/
    |-- directory1
    |-- directory2
    |-- file1.txt
```

"What's wrong with that?" you may think.

The thing is that at first, i didn't use github to deploy my project on the server, because for some reasons i couldn't access the server via ssh. So i used sftp to transfer the content of my local project onto the server. So now, on the server, the files are as follow :

**Server**

```
htdocs/
    |-- directory1
    |-- directory2
    |-- file1.txt
```

So i moved the content of my local project directly into htdocs, and made everything work after a bit of tinkering here and there.

So that was the initial situation : things worked alright. Then, i managed to access my server via ssh, and went to htdocs to set it up as a git repo (with git init).

Then i cloned the project right there, which gave us the following structure :

**Server after git clone**

```
htdocs/
    |-- github_project/
           |-- directory1
           |-- directory2
           |-- file1.txt
```

Again, i had to modify my htaccess file but it worked.

**Problem**

But now, the issue is that all the url of my website are of the form : www.website.com/**github_project**/xxx

I tried modifying my htaccess again, but with no success (i don't have much knowlege regarding mod_rewrite).

So the question is this : what can i do to keep the same directory structure, and still be able to access my pages with www.website.com/xxx , instead of www.website.com/github_project/xxx ?

Or is there a solution that would work at the cost of modifying the structure of the directories, while still allowing me to fetch from the remote repo?

Thanks.

Loïc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone the repo into the root of htdocs

```
git clone <url to remote repo> <path to htdocs>
```

or initialize an empty local repo there

```
git init <path to htdocs>
```

Comment: Hello Joran. When i applied your first solution, i got "fatal: destination path './htdocs' already exists and is not an empty directory. So i emptied it (do not forget to remove the hiddent files/directories (like .htaccess, or .git). I launched the clone command again and **it worked**. The directory structure is now **'htdocs/<my files>'** instead of 'htdocs/*git_repo_name*/<my files>'. Thanks a lot.